# WPF Designer Problem loading elements showing cryptic error message

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a rather old project and in VS2017 WPF Designer I some strange message. We are using some self-developed localization module. But I have no clue where to find more information about this file shghxl30.tmp file it is looking for.

[image]

Comment: I tried to start VS with admin rights after experiencing those errors again. Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Most of the times I've seen this all I had to do was switch from Debug to Release (or vice-versa if I was already in Release), rebuild all and then switch back again. Sometimes it requires a quit-and-relaunch of visual studio, and every once in a blue moon a complete reboot.

If that doesn't do the trick then try deleting your bin and obj folders, and also try disabling your virus checker.

Comment: This happens all the time since I am on VS2017, so many quits and reboots happened all the time.

Comment: Maybe virus checker is the root cause... company policies, so unfortunately I cannot change it.